# Google app script - getting all hyperlinks from document

Tags: google-apps-script

There is an old post for doing this ([Get All Links in a Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727341/get-all-links-in-a-document)) but they have deprecated some functions so the code does not work. All solutions do not work because getLinkUrl has been depricated by google

Is there a way to iterate through each element in a google document and determine if it is a url?

Comment: Have you tried all the answers there including the latest ones? If so, [edit] your question to show the exact issue you encountered with some of them

Comment: Just edited, All solutions use getLinkUrl() which has been deprecated.

Comment: Source or documentation link showing depreciation  notice?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#getLinkUrl()

Comment: nevermind, second answer works. It looks like they deprecated the method for the body only.