# Deleting hyperlink and its text using Google Doc API

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

I need to get all hyperlinks in the document and then delete the text to which hyperlink is attached and insert new test. Here is a sample of what I want

[image: sample of my requirement]

I got a lot of resources, solutions and new thing to learn while solving this problem and currently I like using Google Doc API method. Here are the steps I need to complete the task.

1. Get the hyperlink text using textrun.content
2. Get the indexes of hyperlink text given in element array
3. Copy hyperlink and its text to a variable
4. Delete hyperlink text
5. Modify the hyperlink variable according to need
6. Insert new variable value to the same index in document

I am stuck at **STEP 4**, when I try to delete hyperlink text it deletes some of hyperlinks and leaves some others. Here is the code that I tried;

```js
function myFunction() {
    const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    const res = Docs.Documents.get(doc.getId()).body.content.reduce((ar , {paragraph}) => {
      if (paragraph && paragraph.elements) {
        paragraph.elements.forEach(({textRun,startIndex, endIndex}) => {
          if (textRun && textRun.textStyle && textRun.textStyle.link) {
            console.log(textRun.content);
            requests = [
                    {
                        'deleteContentRange': {
                            'range': {
                                'startIndex': startIndex,
                                'endIndex': endIndex,
                            }

                        }

                    },
                ]
            Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({'requests': requests}, DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getId());
          }
        });
      }
    }, []);
  }
```

Upon digging further into the problem I find [this section](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/concepts/rules-behavior#deleting_text) which shows the rules of deletion and this might be causing trouble here.

How can I achieve my goal? [Here is the shared document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1eRvnR2NCdsO94C5nqly4nRXCttNziGhwgR99jElcJ_I/edit?usp=sharing) I am working on.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `when I try to delete hyperlink text it deletes some of hyperlinks and leaves some others`?

Comment: I mean when I try the code it deletes some hyperlinks but not all, you can check the code above to see the effect. I have also shared a document on which this error is happening.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot(s) or gif of what you mean?

Comment: Your end format looks a lot like another user in a recent question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727341/get-all-links-in-a-document