# replace text in links with function with input parametr URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs-api

I have a problem with this algorithm in Google Doc script :

I need to go through all the links in Google Doc

get its URL for each link

call the function called "getTextByURL (URL)" with the URL input parameter

and update the displayed link text with the return value of this function.

Used to C#, VBA and Word model, where there is a collection of Hyperlinks,
I have a problem in Google Doc script with this algorithm.

Can anyone advise me?

Thanks, Ilya.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Get All Links in a Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18727341/get-all-links-in-a-document)? If it doesn't, can you [edit] your question and clarify where you are facing a specific problem?

Comment: @andrewjames  thanks! 
the function getAllLinks looks interesting, 
I'll try to put it together with my requirements!